# Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0 not recognising System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010 with .NET 4.0.

I have just started using the MS charting.  When I complie the project, I get following error:

```
The type or namespace name 'DataVisualization' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web.UI' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

And also, in my code, this line has a squigly line underneath it indicating that the namespace cannot be found:

```
using System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting;
```

However, if I go to my localhost to the page that has the chart in it, it renders fine.

The other strange thing is that when I compile (CTRL + SHIFT + B), I will get 3 compilation errors the first time I compile, then when I do it again, straight after, I get 16.

Even though I get the compilation errors above, I can still run the application and everything works fine, but it is really annoying that it won't compile so I must be doing something wrong.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, none of this worked.  I ended up creating a brand new solution and added all the code and it worked properly.  There must have been a gremlin somewhere that I couldn't find.

Comment: I figured this out See my solution below

Answer (score 7):

Ok, figured out the problem.

I looked on Google ... StackOverflow and found this page, but I knew that the problem was not needing to be fixed by starting over.

I have ALL the references and fixed up web.config, and I still got the error.

Answer is to change the .Designer code from

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.Chart chartDailyVolume;
```

to

```
protected global::System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart chartDailyVolume;
```

I had copied and pasted code from another visual studio 2010 project to the page and the designer actually bound it wrong.  When I dragged another Chart to the page and then removed it and compiled fine, I compared my checked in code from TFS to the new fix. Thus I noticed that the Designer.cs actually generated it wrong from a copy and paste even though both were visual studio 2010 solution projects (both with Target Framework of .NET Framework 4)

Comment: Perfect!  Exactly my problem.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Click on Add References in your project and in the .NET Components tab **add the System.Web.DataVisualization**. This should solve your problem.

Answer (score 3):

add reference to System.Web.DataVisualization.dll and add a chart control on your page and delete control for making web.config settings etc.

Check for these enteries in Web.config..  if these available then it should work well.

```
<pages>
  <controls>
    <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting" assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"/>
  </controls>
</pages>
```

2.

```
<add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
```

3.

```
 <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

Comment: To others looking and not getting results. I figured this out See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Have you added the DLL as a reference in your web project? It sounds like you've only included it in the bin folder or something.

Answer (score 0):

Under Project references, add `System.Web.DataVisualization.dll`

> Even though I get the compilation errors above, I can still run the
>   application and everything works fine, but it is really annoying that
>   it won't compile so I must be doing something wrong.

Your actual code is not the one running as it did not compile. If the running instance is still working correctly than the dll is probably somewhere in the bin folder where your exe file is.

Answer (score 0):

This solution (creating a new project) worked for me.  Unlike many other people with this problem, I was not using the designer nor was I using web.config (desktop application).  Recreating a new project and then adding reference and I was able to reference the components and methods.

"Unfortunately, none of this worked. I ended up creating a brand new solution and added all the code and it worked properly. There must have been a gremlin somewhere that I couldn't find."

Answer (score 0):

> I ended up creating a brand new solution and added all the code and it
>   worked properly. There must have been a gremlin somewhere that I
>   couldn't find.

Your gremlin most likely was living in designer file of the page that calls the control. That was my case. The cause of the problem was editing .aspx file and adding control while debugger was running - designer files cannot be edited in this mode. Have to stop the debugger to add controls.

After fixing, rebuild the solution to fix your .dll files.

Yes, starting from scratch would fix the visual studio hiccup in the designer file but it is not always an option.